# Cannot override position:absolute with position:initial in IE only

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position

I would not consider myself a CSS newb (noob?) but this problem has me stumped.

I have a navigation header area with the position set to initial. In IE, however, the page is acting as if the navigation area is set to position:absolute and the page content bumps up and starts underneath the navigation rather than right below it. There is an older CSS declaration which does set the navigation to area to absolute, but this is (should be) overridden.

I have tried adding !important to my "initial" declaration.
I have tried changing it to "static", but then you can't click any of the navigation links.

I could go back and remove the old absolute declaration (and probably will) but I'm genuinely curious as to how to overcome this behavior in IE. I have tested in all other browsers including Android and OS and it displays as expected, however ALL versions of IE, including IE11 on Windows 8.1, give this navigation area absolute positioning.

You can view the problem live here: http://inrvu.flywheelsites.com/sign-up-pricing/ The "Get Started Now" should start below the nav, not at the top of the page. You'll need these credentials to view un: flywheel pw: bizarre-villain

I appreciate any help!

Comment: 'initial' is not part of the IE spec at all, as far as I understand there is zero support for it. You'll have to find an alternative way to achieve what you're looking to do.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan  Interesting. I'd never run into that before and just assumed it was cross-browser compatible. Thanks for the info. Not sure why "static" makes all my nav links unclickable, but I guess that requires further investigation. Thanks for the info!